# Meaning of the linear transformation in sigmoid output for Bernoulli parameter estimation

Tags: regression, self-study, neural-networks, deep-learning

This is found in 'Deep learning' book, chap.6, ~p.178 (http://www.deeplearningbook.org/contents/mlp.html), which discusses the problem of predicting the output class of a binary variable

In this section of the book $y$ is the value of a binary variable, $z:=w^Th + b$ seems to be an affine transformation of $h$, while $h$ is a function of $x$. So at this point basically there is no prescribed relation between $z$ (and by extension $x$) and $y$. We just have that based on the assumption $P(y) = \sigma((2y-1)z)$ (which is advertised as being a Bernoulli distribution), still no prescribed relation between the input and the output.

Then I came across the following puzzling sentence:

> Saturation occurs only when the model already has the right answer, when $y=1$ and $z$ is very positive, or $y= 0$ and $z$ is very negative

which by plugging in the designed distribution yield $P(y=1) \approx 1$ and $P(y=0) \approx 0$... How is that saying anything about the model ? Also why the paragraph says nothing about the meaning of the transformation for $z$ ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the diagram of a simple feed-forward neural network on page 170:

[image: feed-forward neural network]

Section **6.2.2.2** on page 178 is describing using this network with a sigmoid activation to predict the parameter of a Bernoulli distribution given some samples $x_0, x_1, ...$.

Forward propagation (prediction) in this network will look like:

$h = W^Tx + b_0$

$z = w^Th + b_1$

$\hat{y} = sigmoid(z)$

If the model prediction $\hat{y}$ is close to $1$ then $z$, the input to $sigmoid$ was very large, and we are in the nearly-flat region of the sigmoid where the gradient is small therefore where it is hard to learn via gradient-descent i.e. "saturation". But if we ever get to this point then we must already have the right answer, so it is not a problem.

This is because we will never start with an initial guess of $\hat{y}$ near $0$, because our data will be standardized and our random initial weights will be small, so z could never blow up to the saturation region of an incorrect prediction on the first training iteration. Only as we perform gradient updates via backpropagation $z$ will head in the right direction towards $\infty$ until $sigmoid(z)$ is close to the correct prediction and the output error is sufficiently small. So at any time we will either be outside of the saturation region or we will have gotten there by converging to the correct prediction.

A symmetric argument holds for $\hat{y}=0$, where $z$ must be very negative.

Comment: Thanks. First, I am unsure if we are really trying to estimate the parameter of the Bernoulli distribution as the output is 1 or 0 (the class I guess ?). We can recover the parameter by sample mean so that's not a big deal so I will just ignore that point... I find your first paragraph quite explanatory, and yes it seems to rely on having the initial guess $\hat{y}$ and by extension the initial $w$ non pathological. That's quite an assumption to make (not that different from local minimum and gradient descent caveats), are we confident this will hold ?

Comment: The output is not binary, it is any number in [0,1]. It only becomes either 0 or 1 if you apply a threshold afterwards, which is what you would do for classification, but not for probability estimation as we have here. I'm not sure about any way to guarantee that your sigmoid won't saturate. The typical advice is to "be careful with weight initialization" and to keep an eye on them to see if they saturate and try something different (weight initialization, learning rate, etc.) if that happens.